# Symbol's value as variable is void

Tags: debugging, emacs

I am editing my `.emacs` file but, when I load it, I repeatedly get an error back.

Here is the code in the `.emacs` file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/user_name/software/lisp/")
```

The error is

```
An error has occurred while loading '/Users/user_name/.emacs':
Symbol's value as variable is void: "/Users/user_name/software/lisp"
```

What does that error mean and how can I fix it?

Here is my `.emacs` file

```
(setq debug-on-error t)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

;(load "~/Software/ess-5.11/lisp/ess-site")
;(load "~/software/ess-15.03-2/lisp/ess-site")
;(load “/Users/knagdimov/software/ESS/lisp")

(add-to-list 'load-path “/Users/knagdimov/software/lisp/”)
(require "ess-site")
```

Comment: The part of your code that you think is the problem, is not the problem.  What you have for `(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/user_name/software/lisp/")` is just fine.  The problem is elsewhere.  Try placing `(setq debug-on-error t)` at the top of your `.emacs` file, save and restart Emacs -- you will get a more helpful debugging message, and you can edit the question with more details once you get them.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks for the tip. I added that line but, the same error reappears with no new information.

Comment: Go ahead and post your entire `.emacs` file as an edit to the question so that we can be of further assistance.

Comment: It looks like you are not using real double-quotes?  Try just plain old regular double-quotes around the path.

Comment: That changed the error to be : Wrong type argument: symbolp, ess-site

Comment: `(require 'ess-site)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126462/discussion-between-crt-and-lawlist).

Comment: No need to chat -- problem is solved with my previous comment.  There is an example of `(require 'ess-site)` in the documentation:  http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html

Comment: I tried that. Now the error is symbol's function definition is void: defvar-local

Comment: Emacs is now at version 25.  Perhaps you are using an old version of Emacs -- i.e., before the macro `defvar-local` was invented.  You should consider upgrading to Emacs 25.

Comment: yup, exactly! I was using emacs 22.1.1. I installed 25.1.1 and it works like a charm. Thanks for the help, really appreciate it. If you post your answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the edit by the original poster to the question above, we learned that the error relating to the path `/Users/knagdimov/software/lisp/` was due to surrounding double-quotes -- i.e., the original poster had used `“/Users/knagdimov/software/lisp/”` instead of straight double-quotes `"/Users/knagdimov/software/lisp/"`.

The second error message the original poster received after fixing the first error was due to the fact that `(require "ess-site")` should have been written as `(require 'ess-site)` -- i.e., the argument FEATURE needs to be a **symbol** instead of a *string*.

The third error message citing the non-existence of `defvar-local` is because the original poster was using an earlier version of Emacs before the invention of the built-in macro bearing that name.  The comments underneath the question indicate that upgrading from Emacs version 22.1.1 to 25.1.1 resolved the issue.